# Are there any algorithm that solves the following problem in time less than O(n!)?

Tags: algorithm, sports-league-scheduling-problem

Are there any algorithm that solves the following problem in time less than O(n!), like polynomial time?
Otherwise, for this problem, does not anyone have found any polynomial time algorithm, like NP problems?

Input: n (number of elements)

Output: a list of all combinations of two, where, from top of the list, each unit of combinations of n/2 must have all elements.

## Example 1

```
Input: n=4
Output: 
[0, 1], [2, 3],
[0, 2], [1, 3],
[0, 3], [1, 2]
```

## Example 2

```
Input: n=8
Output: 
[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7],
[0, 2], [1, 3], [4, 6], [5, 7],
[0, 3], [1, 2], [4, 7], [5, 6],
[0, 4], [1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7],
[0, 5], [1, 4], [2, 7], [3, 6],
[0, 6], [1, 7], [2, 4], [3, 5],
[0, 7], [1, 6], [2, 5], [3, 4]
```

P.S.
The following answer does not meet the requirements.
The first two (= n/2) pairs ([0, 1], [0, 2]) do not have "3", so the answer does not meet the condition where "0" and "1", "2", "3" must be in the first two pairs.

```
>>> n=4
>>> for i in range(0, n-1):
...   for j in range(i+1,n):
...     print( [i, j] )
...
[0, 1]
[0, 2]
[0, 3]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[2, 3]
```

Comment: Not clear for me. Why for example , for `n = 8`, you don't accept `[0, 1] [2, 4] [ 3, 5] [6, 7]`?

Comment: What you are describing is quite unclear. In any case, if the number of solutions is proportional to n!, there is obviously no way to emit them in less than n! operations.

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by "all combinations of two".  It looks like your requirement is that the pairs in the set do not repeat, but how do you choose between `[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]` and `[0, 1], [2, 4], [3, 5], [6, 7]`? Both seem equally valid but only one appears in the output, so the output is clearly not *all* combinations.

Comment: Looking at output you have only unique pairs. So you have a set of `n*(n-1)/2` elements you need to put into `n-1` buckets of `n/2` elements. Even if you do naive approach it wont be `O(n!)`

Comment: This is a type of (relaxed) Sports League Scheduling problem.  What you are asking for is "*For `n/2` rounds of unique pairings of `{0, ... n-1}` elements with the restriction that every element appears exactly once in every round*".   Please confirm if this is correct. The reduced constraints are significant, which should make this version of the problem much easier (maybe even `O(n^2)`).

Comment: Closer: Please do not close this.  Thought there is a language barrier, it is clear what the OP is asking for and this question can be fixed.  I do not want to have to go through re-opening to be able to answer the question.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: It was not clear to me what the question was. If you think you know, you should fix the question and maybe verify that your fix is what OP had in mind. Or you could ask and answer your own question, and propose it as a duplicate. Leaving comments addressed to "Closer" is practically never effective.

Comment: @rici I have already stated what I think that it is, above, and I am only waiting for that verification.  And answering takes time and I do not want to be prevented from posting my answer because the question got closed in the meantime.  since they changed how this works two weeks ago, I have been closed out like this several times already.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: What change are you referring to? As long as I can remember, closed questions cannot be answered, and I've been caught by that many times over the years. Editing the question to make it answerable is a much better way of discouraging potential closers. IMHO.

Comment: And I think you meant "**find** n/2 rounds", not "**for** n/2 rounds".

Comment: @rici Up until a couple of weeks ago, if I was in the process of posting an answer when a question was closed, I could still finish posting.  Now I cannot.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: Interesting. So all those years, I could have submitted my answers to closed questions if only I'd known that all I needed to do was subvert some client-side javascript. That's what I get for not spending more time on Meta, I guess.

Comment: @rici Yeah, I never noticed until they took it away.  And it's been clobbering me ever since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, this appears to be a type of (relaxed) Sports League Scheduling problem. If I understand what you are asking for, it can be summarized as follows:

Given a positive even integer *N* generate a set of n/2 "rounds" of pairings with the following qualities:

1. A pairing is a pair of two different integers `[a, b]` such that a and b are integers from `0..n-1` and `a < b`.
2. A round consists of `n/2` pairings, such that every element from `0..n-1` appears exactly once in a  pairing in the round, and
3. All pairings are unique across all rounds (that is no pairing ever appears more than once in the complete solution).

Assuming that this is a correct formulation of your problem, then the answer is

**Yes, this can be done in `O(n^2)`**.

Further, not only can it be done, there exists a simple method to solve it for any even N:

For the first round, make n-1 pairs, filling in the first element of the pairs with the integers from `0` to `(n/2)-1` going left-to-right.  This how it would look for `N=8`:

```
[0, ], [1, ], [2, ], [3, ]
```

Then, fill in the second elements with `(n/2)` to `n-1`, but going right-to-left:

```
[0, 7], [1, 6], [2, 5], [3, 4]
```

This completes your first round.

For the next round, copy the first round, but keeping `0` in the same place, move the remaining left-side elements up the list, and the right-side elements down the list.  When an element reaches the end of the list, reverse direction and swap them from first elements to second elements (or vice-versa):

```
    ----------------------->
[0, 7], [1, 6], [2, 5], [3, 4]
    <-----------------------
```

Becomes

```
    ----------------------->
[0, 6], [7, 5], [1, 4], [2, 3]
    <-----------------------
```

Now you just continue this process until you have N/2 rounds:

```
[0, 7], [1, 6], [2, 5], [3, 4]
[0, 6], [7, 5], [1, 4], [2, 3]
[0, 5], [6, 4], [7, 3], [1, 2]
[0, 4], [5, 3], [6, 2], [7, 1]
```

Finally swap any pairings where the first element happens to be greater than the second:

```
[0, 7], [1, 6], [2, 5], [3, 4]
[0, 6], [5, 7], [1, 4], [2, 3]
[0, 5], [4, 6], [3, 7], [1, 2]
[0, 4], [3, 5], [2, 6], [1, 7]
```

If you check this solution you will find that it fulfills all of the constraints.  This solutions works for any even value of `N` and obviously runs in `O(n^2)` time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Your interpretation of this question is correct and with your answer and [a Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Circle_method), I have written a program whose functionality is just I wanted. Again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @foo Glad I could help.  If you think that my post is a sufficient answer to your question then you can mark it as the answer by clicking the green check mark below the up/down votes buttons next to my post.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this problem can be solved in quadratic time. It is not too hard to explicitly construct these pairings.

It is quite helpful to consider a regular (n-1)-gon with one additional point in the middle. Then take the lines through one of the (n-1) endpoints and the midpoint and choose the pairs given by the symmetry of this line.